# explicit deny on AdministratorAccess. AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam

Sorry I'm a bit of a clutz at AWS. I have an IAM user that belongs to a group. with the 'AdministratorAccess' policy attached to it. I further verify that this policy includes full access to IAM. However when i am logged in under that IAM user and I try to create a role for my redshift cluster so that it can load s3 data I get the following error:

> User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/redshift-s3-reader with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy

Can someone help me out? I dont see why there would be an explicit deny clause in an all access role like AdministractorAccess

Comment: If your AWS account is part of an AWS Organization, it's likely that your organization has [Service Control Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) in place preventing accounts from performing certain IAM actions.

Comment: Hey, no this is my home lab.

Comment: OK, well review the IAM policies associated with your IAM user and any IAM groups that user is part of. Search for the word 'deny'.

Comment: thanks i figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access Keys use by this IAM user were compromised a month ago (accidentally uploaded to github) which resulted in AWS putting the account in "quarantine". Included in this "quarantine" was an **explicit deny** to create new IAM roles which you need to remove yourself.

Comment: SO is missing people like you that look "deeper" into an issue.  The issue was a symptom and we need to start training the next generation of developers to treat underlying issues.  The younger generation reads an error message as being the actual error and not what the error "could be".

Comment: happy to be part of the community! :)

Answer (score 3):

Explicit denies take effect over any allow, even AdministratorAccess. The evaluation flow is described on this [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-denyallow). If you're experiencing a denial, then whoever setup the user must have (intentionally or not) included either an inline policy, group policy, etc that contains an explicit deny for `iam:CreateRole`

Comment: thanks I posted+accepted the full solution to my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen this where there are strict IP allowlists set via permissions policies[1].

It's also worth checking "Permissions policies" which can be found under IAM -> Roles -> $ROLE in the AWS console and then under the "permissions" section.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_create.html?icmpid=docs_iam_help_panel